# Paginate data in view without repeating sql queries using ASP.NET mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, pagination

I have a large dataset from a stored procedure that I want to display in pages on an ASP.NET webpage.  I can't make demands of the DBAs, so asking them to support pagination on their end isn't possible.  The data is currently being displayed in a widget that's being populate by an ajax call to an action in my controller.  I want the user to be able to change the page and page size without the stored procedure firing again, but I don't know how to pass the data/model from the getData call to the paginateData call.

Ajax:

```
require(["jquery", "ajax"], function ($, ajax) {
    getData: function () {
        ajax.html({
            url: Router.action("Widgets", "GetData"),
            interval: 3000,
            maxAttempts: 20,
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                $('#view-dataList', $context).replaceWith(response);
            }
        });
    }
    paginateData: function () {
        ajax.html({
            url: Router.action("Widgets", "PaginateData", {pageNumber: pageNumber, pageSize: pageSize, data: ??????}), 
            interval: 3000,
            maxAttempts: 20,
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                $('#view-dataList', $context).replaceWith(response);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Widgets Controller:

```
[Route("GetData")]
public ActionResult GetData()
{
    var model = new DataModel();
    var service = new SqlService();
    var customerID = Identity.Current.OptaviaID.ToString();

    model.RecentActivities = service.LoadData();

    return PartialView(model);
}

[Route("PaginateData")]
public ActionResult PaginateData(int pageNumber, int pageSize, IList<Data> data)
{
    var model = new DataModel();
    var page = model.page.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
    model.Data = page;

    return PartialView(model);
}
```

What is a good way to design this?

Comment: This doesn't quite make sense to me. If you're paginating the data, surely you do that from the beginning? Why differentiate between GetData and PaginateData? Surely the view should initialise with the first page of data. I can't see why you ever need to fetch all the data at once - it sounded like that was what you wanted to avoid?

Comment: @ADyson I can't change the query/stored procedure itself, company priorities and workplace politics.

As I said I'm differentiating between get data and paginate data because i want the user to be able to change the page and page size without making the query again.

Comment: Of course when the page first loads it could be paginated to a default page and size but my question is how to allow the user to change those afterward without executing that stored procedure again.

Comment: Unless you fetch all the data at once and hold it in the page, and then do entirely client-side paging without any kind of ajax request, I don't see how you could avoid it. If your dataset is too large for that to be practical from a performance perspective, then you need to do server-side paging. Necessarily, that involves fetching small chunks of the data each time. Necessarily, that involves fetching small chunks of data from the database each time. So if you _really_ want to do this properly, you'll have to engage with your database people.

Comment: You _could_ cache the whole dataset in the webserver's memory using the session or something, but that's soon going to eat up the webserver's RAM if you have a lot of users, and/or a lot of queries, and/or long-running sessions. Another option is possibly to dump the results of the procedure back into a SQL table (which of course you clear out regularly with a separate job) and then execute the pagination queries from that. That way you only run the original procedure once the first time the webpage is loaded during a user's session.

Comment: @ADyson Just spitballing here - What if I changed GetData's return value to a Json ActionResult and stored that json string as a javascript variable from Ajax's success function for use by PaginateData?  Wouldn't that be stored in the browser?

I don't think the dataset is so large that loading it all in the client is an issue.  We're doing that already.  This would be multiplying the memory used by two (or so?).

Comment: Yeah that's a good idea, if your widget supports using a JS array as the data source (or can be made to) then great. Until or unless the dataset gets unmanageable, then it should be faster for the users as there's no HTTP request every time you want to page or sort, and there's less load on the server. It might increase memory usage in the browser a bit, but hopefully it's not significant. There are lots of existing, free-to-use JS-based grid and table plugins which operate in this way, so it's a common situation and definitely achievable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the return values of `GetData` and `PaginateData` in the controller to return the model in json to be stored in the javascript withing the ajax `success` function and added a new method `DisplayData` to return the unserialized `PartialView`.  I changed `PaginateData` and `DisplayData` to HttpPost calls accepting the model that we stored in javascript.

Javascript (notice that getdata, paginate, and display are tethered together via `success`):

```
require(["jquery", "ajax"], function ($, ajax) {

    var currentData = null;
    var currentPage = null;

    var actions = {
    getData: function () {
        ajax.html({
            url: Router.action("Widgets", "GetData"),
            interval: 3000,
            maxAttempts: 20,
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                currentData = response;
                actions.paginateData();
            }
        });
    },
    paginateData: function () {
        ajax.html({
            url: Router.action("Widgets", "DisplayData"),
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            interval: 3000,
            maxAttempts: 20,
            cache: false,
            data: JSON.stringify({ data: currentData, startIndex: 0, pageSize: 10 }),
            success: function (response) {
                currentPage = response,
                actions.displayData();
            }
        });
    },
    displayData: function () {
        ajax.html({
            url: Router.action("Widgets", "PaginateData"),
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            interval: 3000,
            maxAttempts: 20,
            cache: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(currentPage),
            success: function (response) {
                $('#view-dataList', $context).replaceWith(response);
            }
        });
    }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[Route("GetData")]
public ActionResult GetData()
{
    var model = new DataModel();
    var service = new SqlService();
    var customerID = Identity.Current.OptaviaID.ToString();

    model.Data = service.LoadData();

    Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model), "application/json");
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("PaginateData")]
public ActionResult PaginateData(DataModel data, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
{
    data.Data = data.Data.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
    Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), "application/json");
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("DisplayData")]
public ActionResult DisplayData(DataModel data)
{
    return PartialView(data);
}
```

Now in my javascript I can call `getData` on page load to get the data, get the default page and count, and display it, but I can also call `paginateData` when the user changes the page or changes the page size to get the new page and display it without querying the database again which answers this question.

Comment: It's recently been pointed out to me that this can be bad because we're passing the large dataset back and forth between client and server.  Getting the requested page of data could be done entirely in javascript to avoid this.  Tendencies of a backend developer learning front end stuff :p